# how to map crawled locations to existing locations in the database

Tags: google-maps, solr, lucene, web-crawler, search-engine

**Background**: I am building a website which crawls data from real-estate websites (a sample project) in hong kong. I crawl different websites, for various property listings. Hence I get a variety of locations formats from the raw crawled locations

**Example**:
few **Samples** of raw crawled locations:

- **North Point**
- 8, Java Road, **North Point**, Hong Kong
- Hong Kong Island , **North Point**

As can be seen from the above addresses, the same district in hong kong, that is  **North point** can have many forms, few have been listed above. Issue is that this data doesnt make sense unless it is mapped/structured

**Requirement**:
I want some elegant solution, to be able to map these raw crawled locations to a pre-defined set of values. One way I can think of is, create a database of locations (I am using mysql), and find out the matching locationId for each crawled raw location.
If the above scheme sounds good, then my database would have fields like the below:

LOCATION_REF, country, state,city, locality, subLocality1, subLocality2, lat, long

**Additional information**: I am also using apache solr (lucene) to built this website, so any solr related matching suggestions are also welcome

**Thoughts**: I think there must be some predefined APIs to do things like this, because almost every app I see have location based searching and filtering. Is there a google api to do this? If yes, I would appreciate if anyone could help with good examples

PS: I use Jsoup to parse data from the pages (to extract raw location)

Comment: Can someone please give me some leads instead of randomly down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a way to do it, and Google geocoding anwers all the questions that I asked.
Google geocoding API maps the raw address format to its own format, gives structured data of the location based on the location hirarchy (example street number, neighbourhood, locality etc etc  . This is what I needed

Here is the link for reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro